# Constructor argument passing

Tags: java

All - I am new to Java and OOP - trying to get my teeth into Constructors.....can anyone please guide me as to why the constructor below returns 0 and not 51? My apologies if it is typo but I have been looking at this for a while.

```java
      //Create a MyClass class
      public class ListD 
      {
         int x;  // Create a class attribute

         // Create a class constructor for the MyClass class
         public void listD() {
           x = 51;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
         }
         public static void main(String[] args) {
            ListD myObj = new ListD(); /* Create an object of class MyClass (This 
                                          will call the constructor)*/
            System.out.println(myObj.x); // Print the value of x
         }
      }
```

Comment: `public void listD()` is not a constructor. I recommend using a tutorial on constructors, like [this one by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: `public void listD()` is not a constructor, `public ListD()` is.

Comment: got it - thank you - very much appreciated!

Comment: Constructors don't return anything. They just create the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that, 
1) Constructor do not have any return type. 
2) Constructor have same name as class name.

[Java Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

```
public class ListD 
 {
      int x;  // Create a class attribute
      public ListD() //removing return type as this is constructor 
      { 
        x = 51;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
      }

     `public static void main(String []args){
          ListD  myObj = new ListD (); // Create an object of class MyClass (This will call the constructor)
            System.out.println(myObj.x); // Print the value of x
     }
}
```

and Yes here it gives you your desired output!

Answer (score 1):

In your example above:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListD myObj = new ListD(); // Create an object of class MyClass (This will call the constructor)
    System.out.println(myObj.x); // Print the value of x
}
```

You should call the void method first to get the x value to be 51

```
myObj.listD();
System.out.println(myObj.x);
```

Additionally, you should have getters and setters to encapsulate x.
Agree that you should follow the tutorial previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor name should be the same as class name and constructors does not allow any return type. See the following constructor declaration:

```
      //Create a ListD class
      public class ListD {
          int x;  // Create a class attribute

          // Create a class constructor for the ListD class
          public ListD(int x) {
              this.x = x;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
          }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          ListD myObj = new ListD(51); // Create an object of class ListD and pass initial value of 'x' (This will call the constructor)
          System.out.println(myObj.x); // Print the value of x
      }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. One should rather explain the problem, and how it can be solved.